# Pasar datos de padre a hijo ionic2

Tags: ionic, angularjs-2.0

Hola quiero pasar datos desde un componente padre a un hijo en ionic2, se que se hace con input , pero el problema esta que el dato me lo envia vacio,usando una aplicacion angular2 normal , me envia los datos sin problemas, pero usando ionic , no se que pasa.

tabs.ts (El hijo)

```
import { Component,Input,OnInit,Directive} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  templateUrl:'tabs.html',
  selector:'tabs-root',

})
export class TabsPage implements OnInit{
    @Input() listaPaginas:Array<any>;
    @Input() segundo:string;
  // this tells the tabs component which Pages
  // should be each tab's root Page

  constructor() {

  }
  ngOnInit(){

    for(let i=0;i<this.listaPaginas.length;i++){
        console.log(this.listaPaginas[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

transacciones.ts Padre

.............
..............

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-transacciones-examples',
  templateUrl: 'transacciones-examples.html',

})

export class TransaccionesExamplesPage {
  transactions:any;
  latitud:any=null;
  user:string="juanito11";
  cargando:Boolean=false;
  longitud:any=null;
  addingPage:Component=AddingPage;
  listaPaginas:Array<any>=[];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.cargando=true;
    this.loadTransactions();

    this.listaPaginas.push(
      {component:HomePage,title:"Home",icon:"home"},
      {component:AboutPage,title:"About",icon:"information-circle"},
      {component:ContactPage,title:"Contacts",icon:"contacts"}      
      )

  }

  loadTransactions(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      Transaction.all()
      .then((os)=>{
        this.transactions=os;
      });
      this.cargando=false;
    },3000);

  }
}
```

el html donde llamo al hijo

```
<tabs-root [listaPaginas]="listaPaginas" [segundo]="user"></tabs-root>
```

Agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Sí no me equivoco te hace falta la referencia al modelo en el padre en tu caso debería ser **`user`** y en la etiqueta usar `[ngModel]="segundo"` o `[(ngModel)]="segundo"`:

```js
import { Component,Input,OnInit,Directive} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
   templateUrl:'tabs.html',
   selector:'tabs-root'
})
 export class TabsPage implements OnInit{
      @Input() listaPaginas:Array<any>;
      @Input('user') segundo:string;
      // this tells the tabs component which Pages
      // should be each tab's root Page
     constructor() {}
     ngOnInit(){
      for(let i=0;i<this.listaPaginas.length;i++){
      console.log(this.listaPaginas[i]);
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: No está utilizando ngModel @alejo8591

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que el ngOnInit se esté ejecutando antes de que el *Padre* le envíe los datos al *hijo*, por eso en consola parece que no están llegando datos, eso puede sumarse a que en la vista del *Hijo* haya algún error.